# What's the easiest way to force-drop a WebSocket connection?

Tags: tcp, websocket

I'm trying to test my WebSocket server in the face of an unreliable client connection.

I would like to be able, at any moment I choose, to forcefully drop a single WebSocket connection on the client side, without sending closing frames or a TCP FIN handshake. The browser itself cannot do this (right?) because it gracefully shuts down each WebSocket when a tab is closed. Other WebSocket connections from the same host (me in other browser windows) should not be affected.

My system is Ubuntu Linux 12.04; my browser is Chrome (but I could switch to any WebSocket-compatible browser to test this).

The server is using Ruby and em-websocket.

Options I've considered:

- `killall -9 $pid_of_tab` but that's a bit rude, and the kernel apparently still closes the TCP connection
- `iptables` firewall rules but that requires root, and it's hard to drop just one connection (from localhost) whilst keeping others alive
- connecting from another machine, then unplugging the network cable or disabling the wifi

The last two would work, but it feels like there must be an easier way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you could do this pretty easily with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project)

Comment: Interesting idea, I hadn't considered that. I ended up using the iptables hack but I'll give WebScarab a try if I need to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `iptables` version (assuming the socket is served on localhost, port 3000):

To add a rule that drops all traffic:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```

To remove that rule again:

```
$ sudo iptables -D INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```